# Index page go empty in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am trying to fetch the visitors name(from visitors table) corresponding to the visitor id(in entry table).How will i do it?

This is my controller code

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('SystemVmsBundle:EntryDetails')->findAll();

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}
```

Added one to one mapping

```
  <one-to-one field="visitorId" target-entity="VisitorsDetails">
    <join-columns>
      <join-column name="visitor_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
    </join-columns>
</one-to-one>
```

Now my index.html.twig is like

```
   {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ path('entrydetails_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.visitorId }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ entity.sessionId }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.entranceId }}</td>
     </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

But the index page is showing as an empty page. What is the error?

If i remove the '{{ entity.visitorId }}',it works fine! How to show the visitor id and name of the visitor(from visitorDetails table) in the index page?

Comment: Do you loop through the results array or is that your complete template? Because your passing `entities` as variable and not `entity`. SF2 has an excellent debugger (only available if the page is *valid* html afaik), did you look at its output?

Comment: @nietonfir..yeah i am looping..edited the question to avoid confusions! :-)

Comment: well, do you have any values in the array? Either dump it in the controller and exit afterwards or dump it in twig.

Comment: Yes it has the values!

Comment: The problem is with VisitorId i guess. Because overwriting the GetVisitorId to return a static value solves the problem. But don noe how to figure out it!

Comment: Even `visitorId`? Did you update your schema? Do you insert any value to the relationship when creating the entity?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45609/discussion-between-dency-g-b-and-nietonfir)